# Optimize in a single statement

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

[image]

How to get the total count by "paid by"
[image]

```
SELECT sum(CASE 
            WHEN Paid BY = 'Credit'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS Credit sum(CASE 
            WHEN Paid BY = 'Debit'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS Debit etc.
    ,
FROM payment
```

Is there a way to write this in a single statement without having to write one statement for each payment type?

Comment: which dbms do you use?

Comment: Just updated redshift

Comment: Ahh.. Sorry to say but you are pretty much stuck with case when then. Redshift is based on an ancient version of postgres which doesn't have *a lot* of features which are pretty common these days in other dbms dynamic pivot for example. ALthough it can be done [it's not worth the effort](http://blamblogger.blogspot.com/2017/11/how-would-you-do-dynamic-pivot-sql-in.html)

Comment: Thanks@venky__ this is a learning

Comment: probably you should consider `select [Paid by],count(*) as count from source_table group by [Paid by]`. This will give you a long table instead

Comment: @Onyambu I don't think that syntax works in Amazon Redshift. Do you have a documentation reference?

Comment: @Onyambu it just worked. Thanks

Comment: @JohnRotenstein not really and that is why i structure my comment as *probably*

Comment: Table had 12 distinct paid_by values. count(*) as count just listed all 12 with its count.